# Weird error from spliting a function template into the header file in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Here is the code.

```cpp
// Simulated_Annealing.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "Simulated_Annealing.h"

#include <cmath>
#include <random>

#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template<typename energy_function, typename temperature_function, typename next_function>
double simulated_annealing(double i_old, int c, double step_size, const energy_function& ef, const temperature_function& tf, const next_function& nf) {
    auto   e_old = ef(i_old);

    auto i_best = i_old;
    auto   e_best = e_old;

    static std::mt19937_64 g{ std::random_device{}() };

    std::uniform_real_distribution<decltype(e_old)> rf(0, 1);

    for (auto i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        auto i_new = nf(i_old, step_size);
        auto e_new = ef(i_new);

        if (e_new < e_best) {
            i_best = i_new;
            e_best = e_new;
        }

        if (e_new < e_old || std::exp((e_old - e_new) / tf(i)) > rf(g)) {
            i_old = std::move(i_new);
            e_old = std::move(e_new);
        }
    }
    return(i_best);
}

auto ef = [](double x) {
    if (x <= 10) {
        return x * x;
    }
    else {
        return (x - 10) * (x - 10) - 10;
    }
    };

auto tf = [](double k) {
    return 1 / k;
    };


double nf(double x, double step_size) {
    static std::mt19937_64 g{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::normal_distribution<decltype(x)> d(0, 1);
    return x + d(g) * step_size;
}

int main()
{
    double root = 9;
    std::size_t count = 10000;
    double step_size = 3.0;
    root = simulated_annealing(root, count, step_size, ef, tf, nf);

    std::cout << "Result: " << root << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It is OK but when I cut this part into the header file and the header file looks like

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template<typename energy_function, typename temperature_function, typename next_function>
double simulated_annealing(double i_old, int c, double step_size, const energy_function& ef, const temperature_function& tf, const next_function& nf) {
    auto   e_old = ef(i_old);

    auto i_best = i_old;
    auto   e_best = e_old;

    static std::mt19937_64 g{ std::random_device{}() };

    std::uniform_real_distribution<decltype(e_old)> rf(0, 1);

    for (auto i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        auto i_new = nf(i_old, step_size);
        auto e_new = ef(i_new);

        if (e_new < e_best) {
            i_best = i_new;
            e_best = e_new;
        }

        if (e_new < e_old || std::exp((e_old - e_new) / tf(i)) > rf(g)) {
            i_old = std::move(i_new);
            e_old = std::move(e_new);
        }
    }
    return(i_best);
}
```

and try to run, it says Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State    Details
Error    C2760    syntax error: '{' was unexpected here; expected '}'    C:\Users\R\source\repos\cppProjects\out\build\x64-debug\cppProjects    C:\Users\R\source\repos\cppProjects\Simulated_Annealing\Simulated_Annealing.h    15

But the format should be correct?

Comment: The header file looks like it is missing some includes. What happens if you add them?

Comment: @RetiredNinja what includes is it missing?

Comment: `#include <cmath>` and `#include <random>` `#include <iostream>` is not necessary and should probably be removed although leaving it would not cause an error.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Oh thank you I added them and now it is OK. But Visual Studio didnt give me the information (didnt include necessary header files) when I try to build.

Comment: Also, `#include <utility>` for `std::move`.

Comment: @heapunderrun Thank you. do you remember these or should I get these information from IDEs or compilers?

Comment: Some of it is either obvious or just something you learn over time. Take `std::mt19937_64` as an example. I know that requires the `random` header, but if I didn't I could look it up here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine and see the header listed.

Comment: @RetiredNinja what's the differences of including these two files in the header and in the cpp file?

Comment: If you moved `#include "Simulated_Annealing.h"` after the other includes it would work, but only by accident. Change the order and it breaks again. The best practice it to include what you use where you use it and that every file should work on its own.

Comment: I usually just check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) anyway. Sometimes it's possible to find out the header by clicking on the identifier and pressing F12, but this rarely results in the officially correct header: sometimes it opens some Microsoft's internal header like `<xutility>` or some other header that transitively includes the correct one. Better have cppreference handy.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I see, so it is like it is compiled by order?

Comment: @user900476 with the function you moved from the source '.cpp' to the header  '.h' file you must move the necessary '#include' statements as well, since the function is using other library members. In this case, copy:  #include <cmath>, 
#include <random> from the '.cpp' file to the top of the '.h' file (under #pragma once
#include <iostream> in the header file)